# Is there a way to get a classes width in a directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How do I go about getting a elements width in a directive?

In my case a directive gets called multiple times and I have to pass through the element parameter to know what element is being called.

However I do not know how to get a class inside that elements width?

For example I have a class called labels so I have done something along these lines:

```
console.log(element.find(.labels).width());
```

This however doesn't work it brings back zero... even though there is a length of 1. code below:

```
console.log(element.find('.labels').length);
```

So obviously it seems to be thinking that the class is an object but from what I can tell it is not.

I should also point out that the element I am trying to get a width of has a transform css property on it.. I don't think this will effect what I'm trying to do though.

https://jsfiddle.net/2g13wmxz/

Comment: Post more of your directive. HTML and JS.

Comment: added a jsfiddle of my directive and html

Comment: What do you get back from console.log(element.find('.labels').length);?

Comment: I actually am starting to think there isn't a way to do this but I get two logs the first one being 1 then the second being 2

Comment: Can u remove the length and just show us what comes back from the .find? I mean, arent u just trying to find a child element? That should be trivial... no?

Comment: It finds an array with two objects inside. I can find them fine but I can't for the life of me get the width... I've even added unique ID's and the tried to find the width of those and still returns back as zero. I am trying to find the width of an SVG child element.. I might be missing something about SVG's that prevent you from finding the width of child elements

Answer (score 0):

I've done something simila for height, here would be an adaptation for width (haven't tested though):

```js
angular.module('app')
  .directive('findWidth', function($timeout) {
    return {
      type: "A",
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $timeout(init, false);

        function init() {
          var offsetWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
        }
      },
    };
  });
```

PS: You might not need the timeout trick

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

Comment: If I did this, it wouldn't be the width I am looking for. Inside the top level element there is children I basically need the child that has a class name of labels width not the element parameters width